# Raspberry Pi 4 B no audio on any OS

Tags: pi-4, audio

Guys I'm out of ideas. I've tried to get audio running on my Raspberry Pi 4 Model B (4GB RAM)
I've tried it with Buster Full/Lite and LibreELEC.
connected to my Samsung 4K screen via HDMI
Same situation:
Resolution max 1024x768, which tells me it doesn't properly recognise it.
what did work was to manually add a FullHD mode, but thats just the lesser issue, yet might be a pointer to the actual issue.

I have no audio, HDMI (either port) or Composite, it is the same.
I've tried forcing HDMI mode to exclude DVI several and different OS, to no avail.
Does the Pi 4 need some special treatment to get it to work?
The only thing which comes to mind is the power supply lacks about 0,3W of the recommended setting, could that be a cause?

Comment: Have you tried the latest Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop 2nd Dec 2020,then fully updated? https://www.raspberrypi.org/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-32-bit

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you did try doing this but try changing the output of audio from AV port to other output. On the sound bubble on raspberry screen, right click and change the output. Maybe it would work. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting to a bluetooth speaker. Mine had a similiar issue but I managed to get sound via bluetooth